# Impact of converting image to grayscale

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I am seeing many Machine learning(CNN) tutorial which converts the read image in grayscale. I want to know how the model will understand original color/use color as one identification criteria if the colors are converted throughout the model creation ?

Comment: It wont. If the model only gets gray scale data it will just learn to model grayscale data. A model cant understand data that it has never seen. It seems to me that those tutorials use grayscale only to illustrate a simplistic version of CNN, easier to test and understand.

Comment: If colour is an important discriminant in your application, you are at liberty to, say, convert to Hue, Saturation and Lightness (HSL) colorspace and take the Hue channel as your greyscale. What I am saying is there are many ways of generating a single, representative channel without it necessarily being a conventionally calculated greyscale.

Comment: If the images are achromatic, colors are undistinguishable. In many real-world applications, color information is of no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In consideration with colours, there can be 2 cases in an image processing problem:

- Colours are not relevant in object-identification

  In this case, converting a coloured image to a grayscale image will not matter, because eventually the model will be learning from the geometry present in the image. The image-binarization will help in sharpening the image by identifying the light and dark areas.
- Colours are relevant in object-identification

  As you might know that all the colours can be represented as some combination of three primary RGB colours. Each of these R, G and B values usually vary from 0 to 255 for each pixel. However, in gray-scaling, a certain pixel value will be one-dimensional instead of three-dimensional, and it will just vary from 0 to 255. So, yes, there will be some information loss in terms of actual colours, but, that is in tradeoff with the image-sharpness.

  So, there can be a combined score of R, G, B values at each point (probably their mean (R+G+B)/3), which can give a number between 0 to 255, which can eventually be used as their representative. So that, instead of specific colour information, the pixel just carries the intensity information.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to Shashank's answer.

1. A model when fed with an image, does not perceive it as we do. Humans perceive images with the variations in colors, stauration of the colors and the brightness of it. We are able to recognize objects and other shapes as well.
2. However, a model sees an image as a matrix with a bunch of numbers in it (if it is a greyscale image). In case of a color image, it sees it as three matrices stacked above one another filled with numbers(0 -255) in it.
3. So how does it learn color? Well it doesn't. What it does learn is the variation in the numbers within this matrix (in case of greyscale image). These variations are crucial to determine changes in the image. If the CNN is trained in this respect, it will be able to detect a structure in the image and can also be used for bject detection.